# Problem to generate HTML page via XML and XSL (i18n context)

Tags: xml, xslt, internationalization

I try to use key translation system to internationalize a xsl.
I have a main xsl file which references keys and which imports another xsl with all the keys (english or french).
Problem: with the french language, we have simple quotes in our words.
Results: my final HTML page is not correctly generated

After some researchs:
I try to replace the simple quote with &apos.
I try to replace the simple quote (') with double simple quotes ('')

Main XSL file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:import href="translation_fr.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

(other contents ...)

<table class="report-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="report-sub-title" colspan="4"><xsl:value-of select="$lang.mainData"/></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

(other contents ...)
```

I18 FR XSL

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:variable name="lang.mainData" select="'test d'un apostrophe'"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My HTML is not generated when i use simple quote in the xsl:value-of and select. I expect: 'test d'un apostrophe' string displayed in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really use an XSLT 2 processor and that way you can use XPath 2 at the expression level of the `select` attribute then you can solve it with `select="'test d''un apostrophe'"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-StringLiteral on the rules for string literals) but it seems easier to just use

```
<xsl:variable name="lang.mainData" as="xs:string">test d'un apostrophe</xsl:variable>
```

(make sure the stylesheet then declares `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common situation about delimiters when you have a hosted language: in this case, XSLT as XML vocabulary and XPath as string in some attribute. Such common that it was foreseen in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Introduction):

> XPath expressions often occur in XML attributes. The grammar specified
>   in this section applies to the attribute value after XML 1.0
>   normalization. So, for example, if the grammar uses the character `<`,
>   this must not appear in the XML source as `<` but must be quoted
>   according to XML 1.0 rules by, for example, entering it as `&lt;`.
>   Within expressions, literal strings are delimited by single or double
>   quotation marks, which are also used to delimit XML attributes. To
>   avoid a quotation mark in an expression being interpreted by the XML
>   processor as terminating the attribute value the quotation mark can be
>   entered as a character reference (`&quot;` or `&apos;`). Alternatively,
>   the expression can use single quotation marks if the XML attribute is
>   delimited with double quotation marks or vice-versa.

Following that quote, your XSLT instruction would look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="lang.mainData" select="&quot;test d'un apostrophe&quot;"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="lang.mainData" select='"test d&apos;un apostrophe"'/>
```